# UNION in a subquery throwing the numbers

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, union

I'm working on a project for a landing page. Basically, there are multiple criteria that the user can select that will run a query on a DB2 database and return the results. The queries are broken down into various pieces that are assembled depending on user criteria and parameters inserted. While I'm having some difficulty with some that are return giant datasets pulled from even larger tables and joins, there's one that stands out as an oddball when I run some performance numbers on the database.

One thing that all of these fully-assembled queries have in common is that they are filtered on a list of use ids. There are half a dozen or so of these queries that return datasets of varying sizes. Most of them are pretty straightforward, ie:

```
TABLE.COLUMN IN (subquery with a few joins that returns a column of user ids)
```

These subqueries take diddly for time to run by themselves. However, one of these requires a union. Essentially, one table contains a key that has to be used to gather user ids from two different tables, so two sets of user ids must be unioned to get a single list for the subquery, ie:

```
TABLE.COLUMN IN (subquery UNION subquery)
```

It's my guess that the DB2 optimizer runs into a lot more limitations when going over a subquery with a union than one with a simple series of joins and can't handle it as well. This particular subquery is middle-of-the-road when it comes to the amount of data it collects, so it's not an issue with a giant dataset.

I'm wondering what alternatives I might have to a union that would at least bring this subquery in line with the others. It's a bit maddening that making changes may help this particular case, but show a detriment to the others, or vice versa. I've tinkered with a few things, but with no luck. The explain plan shows that the proper indexes are being utilized, at least. I know that I don't have much in the way of examples, but these queries are pretty massive overall and it would be difficult to post the necessary data concisely, but let me know if it's necessary and I'll try to knock something together. Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try changing the `UNION`  to `UNION ALL` in the subquery?

Answer (score 2):

You try these two alternatives to a `union`:

```
WHERE   TABLE.COLUMN IN (subquery1)
        OR TABLE.COLUMN IN (subquery2)
```

Or using filtering joins:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TABLE T
LEFT JOIN   
        (
        subquery1
        ) f1
ON      f1.COLUMN = T.COLUMN
LEFT JOIN   
        (
        subquery2
        ) f1
ON      f2.COLUMN = T.COLUMN
WHERE   f1.COLUMN IS NOT NULL
        OR f2.COLUMN IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: I was able to modify the second to work with what I have, but unfortunately, it had a pretty severe performance penalty over the UNION subquery. I don't know if the first can be self-contained well enough to fit into what I already have.